# Getting Fail with error 'ERC20: insufficient allowance'

Tags: solidity, testing, erc-20-approve

First I'm deploying **Cafe** contract and get **deployedId** from it and then deploy **CAFToken** contract with **deployedId** of cafe contract. I've also added deploy script and test case, I guess everything is going correctly but somehow getting *ERC20: insufficient allowance* error while calling **sendToken** function. May be I miss something can you please guide me on this.

Cafe Contract:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.9;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";

contract Cafe is Ownable {
    address public cafeToken;

    function setCafeToken(address _cafeToken) public onlyOwner {
        cafeToken = _cafeToken;
    }

    //send token to other receipent
    function sendToken(address _receiverAddress, uint _tokenAmount) public {
        require(_tokenAmount > 0, "token should be more than 0");
        IERC20(cafeToken).transferFrom(
            address(this),
            _receiverAddress,
            _tokenAmount
        );
    }

    // Get rewards of user has 10 or more than 10 tokens
    function getRewards() public returns (bool) {
        require(
            IERC20(cafeToken).balanceOf(msg.sender) >= 10,
            "Not enough token for rewards!"
        );
        IERC20(cafeToken).transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), 10);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Cafe Token Contract (ERC20 token)

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.9;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";

contract CAFToken is ERC20 {
    constructor(
        uint256 initialSupply,
        address cafeAddress
    ) ERC20("Cafe", "CAF") {
        _mint(cafeAddress, initialSupply); // mint intial supply to cafe contract
    }
}
```

Deploy script:

```
const { ethers } = require("hardhat");
const hre = require("hardhat");
const delay = (ms) => new Promise((res) => setTimeout(res, ms));

async function main() {
  const Cafe = await hre.ethers.getContractFactory("Cafe");
  const cafeContract = await Cafe.deploy();

  await cafeContract.deployed();

  const Token = await hre.ethers.getContractFactory("CAFToken");
  const cafeToken = await Token.deploy(
    ethers.utils.parseEther("100000"),
    cafeContract.address
  );

  await cafeToken.deployed();

  console.log(`deployed to cafe contract ${cafeContract.address}`);
  console.log("Token deployed to:", cafeToken.address);

  /////////////// Verification ////////////////////
  console.log("Wait for verifying...");
  await delay(5000);

  // verify cafe contract
  await await hre.run("verify:verify", {
    address: cafeContract.address,
    constructorArguments: [],
    contract: "contracts/Cafe.sol:Cafe",
  });

  // verify cafe token
  await await hre.run("verify:verify", {
    address: cafeToken.address,
    constructorArguments: [
      ethers.utils.parseEther("100000"),
      cafeContract.address,
    ],
    contract: "contracts/CAFToken.sol:CAFToken",
  });
}

// We recommend this pattern to be able to use async/await everywhere
// and properly handle errors.
main().catch((error) => {
  console.error(error);
  process.exitCode = 1;
});
```

Test case:

```
const { expect, assert } = require("chai");
const { ethers } = require("hardhat");

describe("Initial Test case", () => {
  let cafeContract, cafeToken, accounts;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const Cafe = await ethers.getContractFactory("Cafe");
    cafeContract = await Cafe.deploy();

    await cafeContract.deployed();

    const Token = await ethers.getContractFactory("CAFToken");
    cafeToken = await Token.deploy(
      ethers.utils.parseEther("100000"),
      cafeContract.address
    );

    await cafeToken.deployed();

    accounts = await ethers.getSigners();
  });

  describe("first", async () => {
    it("check", async () => {
      // Before transaction initial logs and balances

      console.log("Balance", await cafeToken.totalSupply());
      // Send token to another address
      await cafeContract.setCafeToken(cafeToken.address);

      await cafeToken.allowance(cafeToken.address, cafeContract.address);

      // Approve transaction
      await cafeToken.approve(
        cafeContract.address,
        ethers.utils.parseEther("10000")
      );

      await cafeContract.sendToken(
        accounts[1].address,
        ethers.utils.parseEther("10")
      );

      // await token.transfer();
      console.log("--after transaction--");

      const balance11 = await cafeToken.balanceOf(accounts[1].address);
      console.log("Balance-11", balance11.toString());

      assert.equal(balance11.toString(), ethers.utils.parseEther("10"));
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're having this error because you didn't give allowance for your `transferFrom` to succeeds. `transferFrom` works with `approve`.

You can fix this by using `transfer` or by calling `approve` before using `transferFrom`.

Here's how the sendToken function should look:

```
IERC20(cafeToken).approve(address(this), _tokenAmount);
IERC20(cafeToken).transferFrom(
    address(this),
    _receiverAddress,
    _tokenAmount
);
```

or simply

```
   IERC20(cafeToken).transfer(
        _receiverAddress,
        _tokenAmount
    );
```

Comment: Thanks, It's working now :-)